# Pandas Timestamp column fails membership in list of dates when element expression is good?

Tags: pandas, datetime, timestamp

I'm taking the intersection of dates from two dataframes, and filtering the original dataframes (and some other stuff later, so I'm being very explicit).

```
from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": [pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 04:30:00', tz=None),
                               pd.Timestamp('2020-02-01 04:30:00', tz=None),
                               pd.Timestamp('2020-03-01 04:30:00', tz=None),
                               pd.Timestamp('2020-04-01 04:30:00', tz=None)                               
                               ]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": [datetime(2020, 2, 1),
                                 datetime(2020, 3, 1),
                                 datetime(2020, 4, 1),       
                                 datetime(2020, 5, 1)
                               ]})
```

Get the common dates:

```
df1_dates = df1['timestamp'].dt.date.unique()
df2_dates = df2['datetime'].dt.date.unique()
common_dates = pd.np.intersect1d(df1_dates, df2_dates)
```

Each date in `common_dates` list has type: `datetime.date(2020, 3, 1)`

Using the method `df.isin()` the boolean mask says no to everything.

```
df1['timestamp'].isin(common_dates)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: datetime, dtype: bool
```

However, comparing a single timestamp with a standard library expression `x in list`, the timestamp matches:

```
df1['timestamp'][1] in common_dates
True
```

I solved my matching problem using the same conversion that made the list:

```
df1['datetime'].dt.date.isin(common_dates)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
Name: datetime, dtype: bool
```

My question is, **Why does Pandas DataFrame fail membership in date list when the Timestamp element indexed out of the DF is matched successfully?**

Answer (score 1):

The values in `df1['timestamp']` have time components, so they can't match a date unless the time is `00:00:00`. If you change (for example, the second entry):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": [pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 04:30:00', tz=None),
                               pd.Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00', tz=None),
                               pd.Timestamp('2020-03-01 04:30:00', tz=None),
                               pd.Timestamp('2020-04-01 04:30:00', tz=None)                               
                               ]})
```

Then that value will match:

```
print(df1['timestamp'].isin(common_dates))
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: timestamp, dtype: bool
```

Comment: That's a good observation. DF2 works the same way. When I run into trouble working with Pandas, I regularly descend to the element level, and extract a value and inspect it. Strange the `element in list` is True, no?

Comment: Do I smell bug? Same code in Anaconda:  `[datetime.date(2020, 2, 1) datetime.date(2020, 3, 1)  datetime.date(2020, 4, 1)] True` I'm running Minconda3_32-4.7.12 on Win 10 in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: That is weird. I can't see why that behaviour should change between versions...

Answer (score 0):

This is due the object id is different also , so if we already know the list contain datetime.date object , it is better to convert the compared value to date object as well. In you column it is Timestamp not datetime

```
df1['timestamp'].dt.date[0]
datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
df1['timestamp'][0]
Timestamp('2020-01-01 04:30:00')
```

---

Ps : It will not work when you convert your `list` to `set`

```
df1['timestamp'][1] in set(common_dates)
... 
False
df1['timestamp'][1] in common_dates
... 
True
```